# Consider the vectors $u=5i+4j+3k$, $v=-4i-j-k$ and $w=4i+4j-5k$. Compute $|u|+|v|$.

Tags: calculus, vectors

a)$|u|+|v|$

b)$|-6u|+8|v|$

c)$|5u+4v+w|$

d)$\frac{1}{|w|}w$

e)$|\frac{1}{|w|}w|$

For $|u|+|v|$ I have: $\sqrt{5^2+4^2+3^2}+ \sqrt{(-4)^2+(-1)^2+(-1)^2}$ to get $\sqrt{50}+\sqrt{18}$. 
I do not believe this is the right technique. So then I tried $5i-4i+4j-j+3k-k$ to get $i+3j+2k$ which means $1+3+2=6$ which is also wrong.
Therefore since I do not know how to do the first question, I do not know how to do the rest.

Comment: for $|u|+|v|$, your first technique is correct and with the same technique you can do the other questions easily. Computing these are fairly straightforward.

Comment: Your first technique is right. $\sqrt{50}+\sqrt{18}$ is the only correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

These are all straight forward, and you were right at the beginning.  The answer to $a)$ simplifies to $8\sqrt2$.  $e)$ is clearly $1$.

For the others just set them up and knock them down.  Here's $b): 6(5\sqrt2)+8(3\sqrt2)=54\sqrt2$.

$c): 5u=(25,20,12),4v=(-16,-4,-4)\implies5u+4v+w=(9,16,8)+(4,4,-5)=(13,20,3)$.  So we get $|5u+4v+w|=\sqrt{13^2+20^2+3^2}=\sqrt{578}$.

Comment: thank you for your help! I got them all correct now except for part c, if you have suggestions on how to do this that would be very helpful, thank you!

Comment: Hint: calculate the square of the mod. |z|²=z vector dot z vector